# A reduced Noetherian ring injects into a product of fields

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noetherian

I am trying to prove the following:

> If a Noetherian ring $R$ is reduced, then there is an injection from $R$ into a product of fields.

What I know is that every associated prime of $R$ is minimal and for a minimal prime $p$ the localization $R_p$ is field. But I cannot proceed  further. I need some help.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Then why don't try $R\to\prod R_p$ where $p$ runs over the minimal primes? (Btw, in this case $R_p$ is the field of fractions of $R/p$, and recover the answer below.)

Comment: yes this is also possible and first i thought to write that, but Noetherian gives a finite direct product of fields, and so went with that, he can use either of them as he pleases.

Comment: For those who might be interested: the souped-up version of this is called [Goldie's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldie%27s_theorem).

Comment: The statement also holds without the assumption that $R$ is Noetherian. (In this case, the product may be infinite.) See [Tag 02LV in the Stacks Project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02LV]) for the precise statement and the proof.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $R$ is Noetherian, the set of minimal primes is finite, say $p_1,\cdots, p_n$ are the minimal primes of $R$. Since $R$ is reduced the natural map $R\to R/p_{1}\times \cdots \times R/p_{n}$ is injective. Now each $R/p_{i}$ is a domain and hence injects into its field of fractions $Q_i$. Hence we have an injection $R\to Q_1\times \cdots \times Q_n$.

Comment: For dummies like me: the map is injective because its kernel is $\bigcap_i p_i$, and this intersection equals the intersection of all prime ideals in $R$ because any such prime ideal must contain one of the minimal prime ideals, but this intersection is the nilradical, which is zero because $R$ is reduced.