# Two Properties of Perfect Rings

Tags: ring-theory, finitely-generated, local-rings, ring-isomorphism

I came across Kunz's theorem about the characterization of regular rings in characteristic $p$. In the paper that I am reading, the author uses perfect rings to prove this result.

Perfect rings $R$ are defined to be rings of characteristic $p>0$ where the Frobenius homomorphism
$$
F:x \rightarrow x^p
$$
is an automorphism.

He states without explanation some properties of perfect rings and I don't understand some of them.

1. If $R$ is perfect and local such that the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ is finitely generated, then $R$ is a field.
   Why do we need that $\mathfrak{m}$ is finitely generated? We need to show that $\mathfrak{m}$ is the entire ring $R$. But how can we use that $R$ is perfect to show this?
2. If $R$ is perfect and Noetherian, then it can be written as a finite product of perfect fields.

Could someone explain these two properties to me? I would also appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I'm pretty sure you're assuming commutativity, and that is how I will continue.  I'll also denote the Frobenius automorphism as $\alpha$

### (in problem 1) $R$ is reduced

The perfect condition is going to eliminate nilpotent elements.  It is well known that a commutative ring has no nonzero nilpotent elements iff it has no nonzero elements squaring to zero.

That being the case, if $x^2=0$ for some $x\in R$, then $x^p=0$ too, but then by injectivity of the Frobenius map, $x=0$.  Therefore $R$ is reduced.

### (in problem 1)  The maximal ideal is zero

> We need to show that $\mathfrak{m}$ is the entire ring $R$.

No, you need to show $\mathfrak{m}=\{0\}$.  The trick is Nakayama's lemma, and this observation using the perfect condition:

Claim: $\mathfrak{m}^p=\mathfrak{m}$. The Frobenius automorphism has to map $\mathfrak{m}$ onto itself, and $\alpha(\mathfrak{m})$ is a subset of the ideal product $\mathfrak{m}^p$. So there is equality between the three.

Then to continue your problem, by Nakayama's lemma (since $\mathfrak{m}$ is finitely generated and $\mathfrak{m}^{p-1}$ is contained in the Jacobson radical) $\mathfrak{m}=\{0\}$.  This means simply that $R$ is a field.

### (problem 2)

I do not have a complete argument for the claim at this time, but I can get almost all of it.

1. It's [well known](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1936702/29335) that a reduced Noetherian ring has finitely many minimal primes, and that $R$ injects into $\prod \{R/P\mid P \text{ a minimal prime of } R\}$ via the usual map that sends $r$ to its residues mod the various prime ideals.  In fact this is known as a **subdirect product** since it has some more special properties than just injecting $R$ as a subring.
2. $R/P$ is perfect as well when $P$ is a prime, since the Frobenius endomorphism is clearly still onto, and also injective since the ring is a domain.
3. The Frobenius endomorphism of a perfect domain extends to its field of fractions, so that its field of fractions is perfect.

From the foregoing it's obvious that $R$ embeds in a finite product of perfect fields, but I haven't seen a reason (if there is one) that it itself is isomorphic to a product of perfect fields.

Comment: I'm sorry. $R$ is of course assumed to be commutative as you said. Thank you very much for your answer also. For Problem 2, I was thinking that surjectivity of the Frobenius map might be a problem if $R$ is Noetherian. My first guess was a proof by contradiction but your approach is also interesting. Nevertheless, I see much clearer now and I thank you for your time and help.

Comment: One example of this type of ring is a type of periodic ring, one for which $x^p=x$ for all elements.  When such a ring is Noetherian, it is indeed a product of fields... but in general I don't know why it would be a full product of fields.  Does the author in fact need that result? maybe they only need it to be a subring of a product of fields?